# Issues with the delimiter when trying to read a comma separated file (Python, Pandas & .csv)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

###### The problem:

I am trying to reproduce results from a youtube course of Keith Galli's.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv

input_loc = "./SalesAnalysis/Sales_Data/"
output_loc = "./SalesAnalysis/korbi_output/"
fileList = os.listdir(input_loc)

all_months_data = pd.DataFrame()
```

###### problem probably starts here:

```
for file in fileList:
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        df = pd.read_csv(input_loc+file)
        all_months_data = all_months_data.append(df)
        
all_months_data.to_csv(output_loc+"all_months_data.csv")
all_months_data.head()
```

###### this is my output and I don't want row 1 to be displayed, because it contains no data:

[image: row1]

###### The issue seems to be line 3 in one of my csv files. A3 is empty except for commas:

[image: commas in A3]

###### So I go to the csv file, and delete A3 cell. run the code again and I get this:

[image: A3removed]

###### instead of this:

[image]

**What do I have to do to remove the cells without value and to still display everything correctly?**

Comment: It could be something happening in excel. Maybe try to download a fresh version of the csv-file and delete the line using a text editor?

Comment: @fbn001 where can i see this file?

Comment: df.dropna() https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html?highlight=dropna#pandas.DataFrame.dropna

Comment: @inquirer sure, here is a link to all the csv files:
https://github.com/KeithGalli/Pandas-Data-Science-Tasks/tree/master/SalesAnalysis/Sales_Data and to the youtube course: https://youtu.be/eMOA1pPVUc4?t=567

Comment: @fbn001 which file exactly?

Comment: @pieterbons I did this and than something even weirder happens: https://imgur.com/a/kziTjcM

Comment: @inquirer the "first one", april 2019. Sorry.

Comment: That is very weird. Do you see the brackets in the text file? Does this only happen after deleting the row?

Comment: @pieterbons. No, no brackets sir. this is the raw data btw: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KeithGalli/Pandas-Data-Science-Tasks/master/SalesAnalysis/Sales_Data/Sales_April_2019.csv

Comment: @fbn001 You can simply delete the desired line in the frame: df = df.drop(index = [1], axis = 0).  Or do you need something else?

Comment: @inquirer thank you for the advice, I will try it when I am back at jupyter. It's just that I want to understand WHY this happens - and keeping the same code displayed in the course.

Comment: @fbn001 Also try to print the number of measurements print(df.shape). See what extension the file is saved with. It happened to me when an extra comma appeared or, on the contrary, it was missing (I don’t remember exactly).

Comment: When I download your file, delete the empty row using Notepad++ and then run your code the results is exactly as expected. 
When you do not want manual actions, simply drop the empty row in python using all_months_data.dropna() as suggested by Ze'ev Ben-Tsvi

Comment: @Ze'evBen-Tsvi Thank you. This seems to be the easiest workaround. I am still confused though, why this happens. If I learn why this issue occurs, I will come back and explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand, WHY this weird problems occured, but I figured out a workaround to change the data and save everything in a new csv file:

```
all_months_data_cleaned = all_months_data.copy()
all_months_data_cleaned = all_months_data.dropna()
all_months_data_cleaned.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
all_months_data_cleaned.to_csv(output_loc+"all_months_data_cleaned.csv")
```